# Find the degree of the $P(x)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, contest-math

Let $P(x)$ be a polynomial and the equality $P(x)=x(1-x)Q(x)$ holds for all real $x$. Suppose that:

$$Q(x)=Q\left(\frac 1{1-x}\right)$$
holds for every $x≠0,1$. Find the degree of the $P(x)$.

---

My attempts:

We can prove that $Q(x)$ must be a polynomial. Because $$Q(x)=\frac {P(x)}{x(1-x)}$$

Since, $P(x)$ is defined for all $x\in\mathbb R$,this forces $Q(0), Q(1)$ must be defined. Thus, $Q(x)$ is polynomial.
Where $Q(x)$ is undefined for $x=0,1$.

Then, I wrote let $Q(x)=ax+b,a≠0$

$$ax+b=a\left(\frac 1{1-x}\right)+b\implies x=\frac 1{1-x}$$

This shows that, at least $Q(x)≠ax+b$. But, for high degree $Q(x)$ this method gets complicated.

In general, I don't know how to use $$Q(x)=Q\left(\frac 1{1-x}\right)$$

---

Is it ok starting from:

$$ax+b=a\left(\frac 1{1-x}\right)+b\implies x=\frac 1{1-x}$$

Comment: I would presume that the fact that $Q$ is a polynomial is implicit in your question. Have you considered using a compactness argument to show that Q is a bounded as a function $\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ (or $\mathbb C \to \mathbb C$ for that matter)

Comment: "*We can prove that Q(x) must be a polynomial*" $\;-\;$ No, you cannot prove that, since $Q(x)$ is not a polynomial in general. But you don't need $Q(x)$ to be a polynomial in order to answer the question.

Comment: @dxiv $Q(x)$ must be polynomial, Because otherwise I get a contradicton.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: $\;$ the question is about $\,P(x)\,$, so write the relation in terms of $\,P(x)\,$ alone:

$$
Q(x)=Q\left(\frac 1{1-x}\right)
\;\implies\;
\frac{P(x)}{x(1-x)} = \frac{P\left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right)}{\frac{1}{1-x} \cdot \frac{-x}{1-x}}
\;\implies\;
P(x) = -(1-x)^3 \, P\left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right)
$$

---

[ *EDIT* ] $\;$ For verification, $\,\deg P \le 3\,$ in order for the RHS of the last equality to be a polynomial of the same degree with the LHS. The general solution is $\,P(x) = a x^3 - b x^2 - (3 a - b) x + a\,$ with arbitrary $\,a,b \in \mathbb R\,$, as verified [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%28a+x%5E3+-+b+x%5E2+-+%283+a+-+b%29+x+%2B+a%29+%2F+%28+x%281+-+x%29+%29+where+x+%3D+1+%2F+%281+-+z%29). So, in the end, $\,\deg P = 3\,$ when $\,a \ne 0\,$, or $\,\deg P = 2\,$ when $\,a = 0, b \ne 0\,$, or $\,P(x) \equiv 0\,$ when $\,a=b=0\,$.

---

[ *EDIT #2* ] $\;$ The following addresses the question raised in comments [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4494895/find-the-degree-of-the-px/4494899?noredirect=1#comment9430533_4494899), [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4494895/find-the-degree-of-the-px/4494899?noredirect=1#comment9430375_4494901) whether the first equality in the problem is supposed to be interpreted as $\,x(1-x) \,\mid\, P(x)\,$, in which case it follows that $\,Q(x)\,$ must be a polynomial, and the second condition trivially implies that it can only be a constant polynomial, meaning $\,P(x)\,$ must be a scalar multiple of $\,x(1-x)\,$.

My reading of the question, on which the answer above was based,  is that $\,Q(x)\,$ is defined by *both* of the given conditions. The second condition is not defined for $\,x \in \{0, 1\}\,$, which suggests that the domain of $\,Q\,$ should be considered to be $\,\mathbb R \setminus \{0, 1\}\,$, rather than the whole $\,\mathbb R\,$. Under this interpretation, the first condition only applies to the domain of $\,Q\,$, *not* including $\,\{0,1\}\,$.

Under the alternative interpretation, where the first condition is supposed to hold on the entire $\,\mathbb R\,$, and assuming $\,Q(0), Q(1)\,$ exist and are finite values, it follows that $\,0, 1\,$ must be roots of $\,P(x)\,$, so $\,x(x-1) \,\mid\, P(x)\,$, which is equivalent to $\,a=0\,$ in the posted solution.

Comment: Ignore previous question.  The conclusion of your analysis *just hit me*. +1: Elegant

Comment: But what is $P(x)$ ?

Comment: @User The question is not asking you to find $P(x)$ but only its degree. Now look at the last equality and ask yourself what the degree of $P(x)$ could be so that the right-hand side is a polynomial of the same degree with the left-hand side.

Comment: @User Immediate from dxiv's analysis that $P(x)$ can have degree no greater than $(3)$, since $~\displaystyle -(1-x)^3 \times P\left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right)~$ must be a polynomial **in** $(x)$.  So, set $P(x) = ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d$, see where this leads, and remember that $a,b,c,d$ must be *constants* such that dxiv's final equation holds for *any* value of $x ~: 0 \neq x \neq 1.$

Comment: Note @User you can use the substitution $y := 1-x$ to make some calculations easier.

Comment: @user2661923 You are right, thank you. I fixed the edit to cover all cases.

Comment: Doesn't $P(x)=x(1-x)Q(x)$ for all reals force $P(0)=0\implies a=0$?

Comment: @Macavity Guess it depends on how you read the question. I added a separate edit about that.

Comment: So we have 4 answer: $3,2, -∞, 0$?

Comment: @User No $0$, just $3,2,-\infty$.

Comment: Sorry, I confused with $Q(x)$.

Comment: Thank you for all your answers. Regardless of whether the first expression in the question is defined on all real numbers or is defined except $0,1$, is the answer always $3,2,-∞?$

Comment: @User It's $\,3,2,-\infty\,$ if the first condition is defined on $\,\mathbb R \setminus \{0, 1\}\,$. Otherwise if it's taken to be defined on the entire $\,\mathbb R\,$ it's just $\,2, -\infty\,$.

Comment: @dxiv Thank you. I loved your answers.

Answer (score 1):

There are three cases two consider. Either $Q$ is zero, $Q$ is a nonzero polynomial, or $Q$ is a nonzero rational function of polynomials. We consider the first two, as the third case is considered by the other answerer.

Assume that $Q$ is also a polynomial. Note that `$\forall x \in \mathbb R: \left|x\right| > 2 \implies \left| \frac{1}{1-x} \right| \leq 1$ holds. By either using compactness of the interval $I := [-2,2]$ or explicitly using the form of $Q$ being a polynomial admit an absolute bound $B \in \mathbb R^+$ for $Q$ on $I$.

Suppose that $x \in \mathbb R$. If $x \in I$ then $\left|Q(x)\right| \leq B$. Otherwise then $\frac{1}{1 - x} \in I$ and so $\left|Q(x)\right| = \left|Q(\frac{1}{1 - x})\right| \leq B$. Observe now that $B$ bounds $Q$ on $\mathbb R$. $Q$ is a polynomial that is constant on $\mathbb R$ and so is a constant polynomial. Thusly either $Q = 0$ in which case $P$ is also identically zero. Otherwise the degree of $P$ is 2.

---

In conclusion: either $Q = 0$ hence $P = 0$, or $Q := C \in \mathbb R \setminus \{0\}$, in which case $P = x(1-x) \cdot C$, or $Q$ is a rational function of polynomials. The latter case is covered by the other answer.

Comment: It is not given that $Q(x)$ is a polynomial, so the rest does not follow. For example, $P(x) = x^3 - 3 x + 1$ satisfies the problem, but $Q(x) = \frac{P(x)}{x(x-1)}$ is not a polynomial.

Comment: Ah! I was assuming that the question asker had simply forgotten to include the fact that Q was a polynomial - as working in the ring of power series is a different matter indeed as you say

Comment: @dxiv in your example $P(1)≠0$

Comment: @User Quoting from your question: "*holds for every $x \ne 0,1$*". You cannot substitute $x=1$ there.

Comment: @dxiv $P(x)=x(1-x)Q(x)$ holds for all $x\in\mathbb R$. So, $P(1)=0$. But, $P(x)=x^3-3x+1$ implies $P(1)=-1$

Comment: @User that only holds in the case that $Q$ does not have a pole at $1$. If $Q$ is allowed to be a rational function then there is the possibility of $Q$ having a pole at $1$. Such is the case in dxiv's solution.

Comment: @user2628206 $P(x)$ is polynomial. This forces $P(0), P(1)$ must be defined.

Comment: @User It is $Q(0), Q(1)$ on the RHS which are not defined, so you cannot substitute $x = 0$ or $x=1$ there.